# Vue composite make function reactive?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, composable

Is it possible to create a composite function such that consumer can provide a reference to a function? In mixins you could just call the consumer method as long as it existed. Here is how I would think this would work but it doesn't. method1 is not reactive. I realize this might be an antipattern. Sometimes you run an async/ajax call and once it's done it would be nice to just run the callback method1 instead of changing a dummy value and running a watch on it in the consumer. Ideas?

-- consuming component

```
setup() {
  let { prop1, method1, method2 } = useComposite();

  method1 = (o) =>
  {
    console.log(o);
  };

  method2();
}
```

composable function --

```
export default function useComposite()
{
  let method1 = ref(()=>{});
  const method2 = () => 
  {
    method1.value("hello");
  };
  const prop1 = ref(o);

  return {
   method1,
   methoid2,
   prop1,
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`method1` is already a ref and used as such. If it's redefined, this should be done like:

```
  method1.value = (o) => ...
```

This is definitely an antipattern. There could be multiple callbacks, while it's limited to one. A more complete solution could use event bus like `mitt` and register handlers for an event.

A proper solution with composition API would involve a watcher. Nothing requires composition API here. It's just callback-based control flow and a step back from promise-based one. If `method2` is asynchronous, it needs to return a promise and be chained in a place it's used:

```
 const method1 = (o) => ...
 method2().then(method1);
```

Comment: I forgot that I could chain promises. Very good, thanks.